# Fitting text within multirowcell in a table

Tags: tables, multirow

Kindly assist in fitting the shown text in column 4. I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{bm,array}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{lineno}
%\linenumbers
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{framed} % Framing content
\usepackage{multicol} % Multiple columns environment
\biboptions{sort&compress} %compresses numerical citations

\usepackage{multirow}
%
%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % to change header and footers
\usepackage{blindtext} % to quickly get a full document
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
 \rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}   
}

\usepackage{makecell,multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\tablistcommand}{% <-- for eliminating vertical space
                             %     before and after itemize
            \leavevmode\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                            }
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{p{#1-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}}

\begin{document}

% \begin{landscape}
   \begin{table}[h]
\setcellgapes{0pt}
%\makegapedcells
\scriptsize

\begin{tabular}{|P{0.2\textwidth}|  P{0.5\textwidth}|  P{0.2\textwidth}| P{0.1\textwidth}|}
    \hline
Dimension & Description  &   Evidence & Weighting \\\hline 

  \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{1.1 Evaluation}}\\ \hline    
 \flushleft  
\textbf{1. Subject}  &   Grasp  $\bullet$ Currency &
 \multirowcell{8}{ 
1.Self assessment statement providing elements of the performance contract for the given year.\\
 2. Course outline \& other learning materials (Handouts, modules,etc)\\ 3. New innovations for teaching \\4. Sample students assignment and exam scripts \\5. Sample marking schemes \\6. Reviews of course materials \\7. Students completion rates on projects and/or dissertation \\ 8. projects from professional development workshops\\ 9. Mastery of content \\ 10. classroom observation} & {}\\
  \cline{1-2} 
\textbf{2. Design}& Conceptualisation &&\\  \cline{1-2}
 \textbf{3. Delivery} & Implementation  &&\\   \cline{1-2} 
 \textbf{4. Management} & Organizational  & & \\  \cline{1-2}
 \textbf{5. Mentoring } & One  &  &\\  \cline{1-2}
 \textbf{6. Assessment}   & $\bullet$ Good  & & \\  \cline{1-2}
 \textbf{7. Teaching }   &   Ability   & &\\  \cline{1-2}
\textbf{8. Academic } & Initiating  & &{} \\
  {}  & {} & {} & \textbf{7}\\  \hline 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{1.2 Student}}\\ \hline
  \textbf{Dimensions 2-6 } & Conceptualisation &    1. SECAT & {}\\ 
  {}   & {}   & {} & \textbf{8}\\ \hline  
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recent `multirow` package can consider column formatting:

```
 \multirow{8}{=}{ ... } % <-- note " = "
```

which considering in your table gives the following (very ugly) result:

[image]

This can be (partly) improved with different schedule of column width. I don't know what is acceptable for you. Let me assumed, that the following table is what you looking for:

[image]

Above table I obtain with using `tabularx` for table environments, use `enumerate` for list in the third column and `textbf{...}` for column headers:

```
\documentclass[preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{calc}

% only for for show page layout 
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}


\begin{document}
   \begin{table}[h]
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\scriptsize
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep, topsep=0pt, partopsep=0pt,leftmargin=*,
                    before=\vspace{-\baselineskip},
                    after =\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                    }
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| >{\bfseries}l | p{0.2\textwidth} | X | c |}
    \hline
Dimension   & \textbf{Description}   &   \textbf{Evidence} & \textbf{Weighting} \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{1.1 Evaluation}}\\ \hline
1. Subject          & Grasp $\bullet$ Currency & \multirow{8}{=}{
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item   Self assessment statement providing elements of the performance contract for the given year.
    \item   Course outline \& other learning materials (Handouts, modules, etc). 
    \item   New innovations for teaching.
    \item   Sample students assignment and exam scripts.
    \item   Sample marking schemes.
    \item   Reviews of course materials.
    \item   Students completion rates on projects and/or dissertation. 
    \item   projects from professional development workshops.
    \item   Mastery of content.
    \item   classroom observation.
        \end{enumerate}                                            
        }% end of multrow
                                         &\\
  \cline{1-2}
2. Design       & Conceptualisation     &&\\  \cline{1-2}
3. Delivery     & Implementation        &&\\  \cline{1-2}
4. Management   & Organizational        &&\\  \cline{1-2}
5. Mentoring    & One                   &&\\  \cline{1-2}
6. Assessment   & $\bullet$ Good        &&\\  \cline{1-2}
7. Teaching     & Ability               &&\\  \cline{1-2}
8. Academic     & Initiating            &&\\  %\cline{1-2}
                &                       &&\textbf{7}    \\  \hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{1.2 Student}}                \\  \hline
Dimensions 2-6  & Conceptualisation     & 1. SECAT &    \\
                &                       && \textbf{8}   \\  \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```